# Subsetting POSIXct, losing timezone

Tags: r, posixct

Please see the R below.  I'm subsetting from a larger time series (which var `dt1` is representative of) and the timezone is getting dropped.  Any suggestions?

```
> dt1 <- as.POSIXct("2011-07-01 13:42:00", tz="America/New_York")
> dt1
[1] "2011-07-01 13:42:00 EDT"

> attr(dt1,"tzone")
[1] "America/New_York"

> df <- data.frame(subsetDate=.POSIXct(character(3)), otherData=numeric(3))

> df$subsetDate[1] <- dt1
df
       subsetDate otherData
1 2011-07-01 13:42:00         0
2                <NA>         0
3                <NA>         0

> attr(df$subsetDate[1],"tzone")
NULL
```

The other problem, besides dropping the tz, is that while the result is still identified `str()` as POSIXct, I can no longer do math on those dates.

```
> str(df$subsetDate)
POSIXct[1:5], format: "2011-07-01 13:42:00" NA NA 

> df$subsetDate[1]+3600
Error in unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) : 
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: Why aren't you just subsetting `dt1` directly with `subset()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. Using `.POSIXct` instead of `as.POSIXct` is a bad idea; it is an internal function not intended to be available; among other things, it doesn't actually convert the internal representation of the date to numeric the way `as.POSIXct` does (this is why math doesn't work).
2. `[<-` drops attributes

To resolve 1, use:

```
df <- data.frame(subsetDate=as.POSIXct(NA_character_, format=""), otherData=numeric(3))
```

Math will work on the above table:

```
> df$subsetDate[1] <- dt1
> df
           subsetDate otherData
1 2011-07-01 13:42:00         0
2                <NA>         0
3                <NA>         0
> df[1] + 3600
           subsetDate
1 2011-07-01 14:42:00
3                <NA>    
2                <NA>
```

For the second point, attribute copying rules are a not always super intuitive, and `[<-` has the tendency to drop attributes.  After all, it isn't always clear whether you want the attributes from the LHS or the RHS.  For your specific problem, you can just set the attributes the way @BondedDust suggests

Comment: Datetimes in R are a constant source of head and error.

Comment: Thank you.  I'd not previously made use of `NA_character_`, and will gladly dispose of `.POSIXct` for allocations.  I appreciate your explanations.

Comment: @joeln, you don't even need `NA_character_`. `as.POSIXct(NA)` works too.

Comment: To potentially help future Googlers, I hit this using dplyr but *only* when the returned table had a single row. The `tzone` attribute was dropped when I had > 1 rows, but stayed with I had exactly 1, which broke my `rbind_all`. Stripping the `tzone` attribute off manually did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it back:

```
  attr(df[ ,'subsetDate'], "tzone") <- attr(dt1,"tzone")
```

It doesn't show up when printed as a dataframe, but it's now there:

```
> df
           subsetDate otherData
1 2011-07-01 13:42:00         0
2                <NA>         0
3                <NA>         0
> attr(df[ ,'subsetDate'], "tzone")
[1] "America/New_York"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'd tried `> attr(df$subsetDate[1],"tzone") <- attr(dt1,"tzone")` which did not work.  Unfortunately this doesn't totally resolve things as the resulting vector can still not be manipulated with math.

Comment: Well, it worked, but it just didn't have the effect you desired with respect to the "+" operator.

Comment: Yes, thank you, you did provide a solution to the issue as I initially described it.